# URL is not persistent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller, static-pages

I've created a static "thank you" page. But everytime I go to `/thanks` it forwards me to a URL like this one: `/thanks#.UVQswKt-WyK`

I've added this in my `routes.rb`:

```
match '/thanks',  to: 'static_pages#thanks'
```

and the file in static pages is called `thanks.html.erb`

All of my other static pages work just fine, if I go to e.g. `/services` , the url stays as it's supposed to.

I'm missing something, but I am not sure what...

Comment: Do you have integrated somethink like oauth or facebook login?

Comment: no, it's a pretty simple, mostly static website. No oauth or any other kind of authentication or login.

Comment: and it also seems as if the thank you page only works on my local machine. If I push things up to Heroku, it says "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Comment: Found the solution myself (and this was a really stupid beginner mistake). I am using AddThis on the thank you page to provide social sharing buttons. They generate a unique URL identifier for their analytics. Can I mark this question is closed?

Comment: please show us rake routes